# Program stuck in Infinite loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, design-patterns, while-loop, infinite

My program is going in infinite loop and does not print required output please help anyone

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Little hint for you: `while(space)`

Comment: that is why they invented a skill named debugging, what is wrong with copy/paste text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 2nd and subsequent iterations of the outer `while` loop, `space` will be initialized with a non-zero value, and then the `while(space)` loop will keep incrementing `space` for a long time until it overflows to a negative value, and then keep looping for a long time further until `space` eventually increments to 0, finally breaking the loop.  When an `int` is evaluated as a boolean, only 0 evaluates as false, all other values evaluate as true. And a 32bit `int` can hold 4294967296 unique values (-2147483648..2147483647), giving the *illusion* that your loop is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(space)
{
    std::cout << ' ';
    space = space + 1;
}
```

When `space` is `1`, this loop will increment `i`, so it keeps looping. It will loop until `space` overflow, and increment until `space` is `0`

You probably want:

```
while(space)
{
    std::cout << ' ';
    --space;
}
```